# Header already sent, error shows core files

Tags: errors, http

I am having an error like this :

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/zk2ba8xn663w/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:5100) in /home/zk2ba8xn663w/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219

How should i approach to solve the problem as error shows the WordPress core files?

This is the line there :

```
if ( !$is_IIS && PHP_SAPI != 'cgi-fcgi' )
    status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

header("Location: $location", true, $status);

return true;
```

can if i use $location in my theme can it cause any problem?
please help

Comment: The error isn't in WordPress core. It almost never is. The problem is that you have a theme or plugin that' throwing an error or printing output too early.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah i  agree,  but why does it points to pluggable.php instead of theme file or plugin file, that's what confuses me

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla somewhere in the theme or a plugin output has started before the `header()` call in pluggable.php, so that's when the error is triggered. Check for white space at the top and/or bottom of plugin files and functions.php in theme.

Comment: Thanks :) ..it was the acf form that ends up in this error. `<?php acf_form_head(); ?>` form needed to placed before the `<?php get_header(); ?>`